# Odoo fields passed through context appear and disappear

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-8

I have a little problem here.. as the title says, I'm passing some variables through the context in Odoo, but, they appear and disappear quickly.
Part of my code:

```
<field name="onetomany_ids" nolabel="1" context="{'employee_id': employee_id,}" >
     <tree string="Invoices">
       <field name="employee_id" />
     </tree>
</field>
```

As you can notice in the name that field is an One2many, it shows a tree with a link that allows adding a new record. So, when I click there, it shows the form, but the values that passed through context don't show. It should show the field employee filled with the employee that came from the previous view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write as following :

```
<field name="onetomany_ids" nolabel="1" context="{'default_employee_id': employee_id,}" >
     <tree string="Invoices">
       <field name="employee_id" />
     </tree>
</field>
```

Comment: it solved the problem, thanks, but why the name change? why to write default_ before the name of the field?

Comment: It will be used in default_get method, so if you want to set something default in field (it only works when you start to creating new record). So it's the pattern of framework to set default value in field by this way.